# How do I find the function value?

Tags: functions

If my answer is 1 over negative 9 does that mean it's undefined? or is this the answer and I can leave it like that? Would it be written as negative 1 over 9?

Comment: What's the question?  What function are you talking about?

Comment: $1$ over $-9$ is perfect well-defined.

Answer (score 4):

$1$ divided by $-9$ is $\frac{1}{-9}$.

$-1$ divided by $9$ is $\frac{-1}{9}$.

The negative of the result of $1$ divided by $9$ is $-\frac{1}{9}$.

Now we have $$\frac{1}{-9}=\frac{-1}{9}=-\frac{1}{9}$$

and we usually write this as $-\frac{1}{9}$.